# Until I fell asleep, I would/used to scroll my smart phone. - is this acceptable?

Tags: modal-verbs, conjunctions, conditionals

**Example 1**

> **As soon as/Once** my father bought me a gift, I would/used to bring it to the school and show it off to my friends.

**Example 2**

> **After** my father bought me a gift, I would/used to bring it to the school and show it off to my friends.

**Example 3**

> **Until** I fell asleep, I would/used to scroll my smart phone.

**Question 1**
Do they all convey a past repeated or habitual thing in the past?

**Question 2**
What is the difference if I use simple past instead of "would" or "used to"? I remember simple past can also indicate a repeated event. Maybe it can also mean a single event, so that is why we use "would" or "used to"?

Comment: **After** would go better with **had given**. or **Whenever...gave** instead of **after...had given**.

Comment: **Once my father bought me gift** isn't quite idiomatic in the sense you want to convey. The verb in the clause introduced by **once** should admit the sense of the action being *fully attained*. So **had given** would be better than **bought**. or *Once I had the gift in my hands, I would take it to school.*

Comment: @TimR But time conjunctions like "once" and "as soon as" can be used to convey a past habitual or repeated event like they are used in my examples, right?

Comment: No, **after** and **once** don't convey anything at all about whether the action was a one-time thing or repeated. *After I swam in that icy water, I would look forward to a warm shower. After I swam in that icy water, I never went swimming again.*

Comment: @TimR Sorry, I am confused. You said no, but aren't the sentences you provided the cases where "once" or "after" are used to convey a repeated thing. oh maybe you're saying they can convey either depending on the context?

Comment: Whether you use "would" or "used to" depends on whether you want to emphasise that it's no longer the case - for that emphasis, "used to" is better, while "would" could refer to something that might happen again (especially if circumstances changed). You don't seem to distinguish these cases in your example.

Comment: Whether the action is a one-time thing or a repeated thing is conveyed  by the matrix clause in your examples. **after** and **once** are compatible with both senses but they don't generate the sense.